# Multiple increment operators on the same line Python

Tags: python, increment

Is it possible to do multiple variable increments on the same line in Python?

Example:

```
value1, value2, value3 = 0
value4 = 100
value1, value2, value3 += value4
```

In my real program I have LOTS of variables that are different but must all be added on with a single variable at one point.

What I am currently doing that I wanted this to replace:

```
value1 += value4
value2 += value4
value3 += value4
...
value25 += value4
```

Comment: Why don't u use list instead or dict?

Comment: `value1, value2, value3 = (v + value4 for v in (value1, value2, value3))`...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create special function for it:

```
def inc(value, *args):
    for i in args:
        yield i+value
```

And use it:

```
value1 = value2 = value3 = 0
value4 = 100
value1, value2, value3 = inc(value4, value1, value2, value3)
```

Comment: This is an interesting way to do it, however still very long to type.

Answer (score 8):

Tuple and generator unpacking can be useful here:

```
value1, value2, value3 = 0, 0, 0
value4 = 100
value1, value2, value3 = (value4 + x for x in (value1, value2, value3))
```

Comment: @MikeMüller, that's not tuple unpacking, that's iterable unpacking of a generator expression.

Comment: @MikeGraham Thanks for the pointer. My wording is not totally correct. In the last line no tuple is created. Fixed. I used  *tuple unpacking* for the more general  *iterable unpacking*.

Answer (score 1):

You can update the variables through the dictionary of the current namespace (e.g. [`vars()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#vars)):

```
>>> value1 = value2 = value3 = 0
>>> value4 = 100
>>> for varname in ("value1", "value2", "value3"):
...     vars()[varname] += value4
... 
>>> value1, value2, value3
(100, 100, 100)
```

Answer (score -5):

There is an easy way by making a list and looping over it:

```
value1, value2, value3 = 0
value4 = 100
valuelist = [value1, value2, value3]
for x in valuelist:
    x += value4
```

Comment: That doesn't work -- ints are immutable, `+=` rebinds the name, not mutates the value

Comment: @MikeGraham Then what would be mutable? Maybe converting value1-3 to these mutable values inside the list may work.

Comment: the solution is just not to try to use mutation here, but rather create and assign new values. http://stackoverflow.com/a/34694027/192839 was a pretty reasonable solution