# Condensing multiple operations to single line in Python

Tags: python

I'm using a for loop that needs to keep track of two count variables (x and y). The way I'm currently implementing this is by adding to each value every iteration:

```
x, y = 0, 0
for i in range(list):
    x += 1
    y += 1
    if x = 103:
        do something()
        x = 0
    if y = 57:
        do something_else()
        y = 0
```

Is there a more pythonic way of keeping two count variables? I know variables can be assigned in the same line:

```
x, y = 0, 0
```

Is there an equivalent for adding to variables?

Sorry, this question is very rudimentary but the closest question I can find is [suggesting using lists, dicts, or functions.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34693927/multiple-increment-operators-on-the-same-line-python)

Comment: No, there is no equivalent for augmented assignments.

Comment: You can get close with `x, y = x + 1, y + 1`

Comment: I'm not sure. Do you want: `zip(itertools.cycle(range(103)), itertools.cycle(range(57)))` ?